# Trying to secure my home network. Is it normal to have this many open TCP ports on my devices?

Tags: macos, tcp

I recently bought Debokee (aka LANscan) & LittleSnitch. I'm wondering if this scan looks strange to anybody? I have a strong suspicion with evidence that my network has been compromised. I am just trying to find out where the holes are.

I am running macOS Monterey v12.6. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This does not look too unusual for me. These devices provide services in your network, so the need to have ports open.

Comment: Those ports are all normal for those devices. What makes you concerned about compromise?

Comment: I agree with Steffen. Nothing special/weird in that scan. Pretty much same as my own setup. And thsi is NOT really a good way to determine of your network is already comprised. The vast majority of infections don't have open ports that you can scan for like this.

Comment: You are running a scan inside your own network, so it is a normal scan.